# change listBox content from MySQL by click

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, listbox

I have a listBox that already populated by MySql table. I want to change the content of listBox anyway user pressing a button, what I done for this is to call sql class creator in my code with new query that filter the data from table, the problem is how to change listbox content in that button event handler?
here is my codes

```
private void shirtSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    string shirt = "SELECT * FROM viewermenu.grament where type = 'shirt'";
    var shirtTable = new DatabaseTable();
    string id = null;
    shirtTable.GetTable(shirt, id);

    listBox.DataContext = shirtTable;

}
```

and xaml side:

```
<ListBox  x:Name="listBox" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NamesTable}}" it HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0" Padding="0,0,0,317" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Height="200" Width="200" >
                <Image Margin="3" Source="{Binding pic_path}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                <TextBox Margin="3" Text="{Binding name}" Visibility="Visible"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and databbase table class:

```
        public DataTable GetTable(String query, String sortBy)
    {
        String connString = "server=192.168.*.**;uid=*****;pwd=****;database=viewermenu";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = sortBy;
        return dataTable;      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mistakes in the given code, correct them and have a try.

1.Add `IsItemsHost` to the `ItemsPanelTemplate`:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

2.Define a `ShirtData` class:

```
public class ShirtData
{
    public string pic_path { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public ShirtData(string path, string theName)
    {
        pic_path = path;
        name = theName;
    }
}
```

3.Set the `ItemsSource` in the code-behind (some pseudocode):

```
.......

var table = shirtTable.GetTable(shirt, id);
var shirts = new List<ShirtData>();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var shirtData = new ShirtData(row["pic_path"].ToString(), row["name"].ToString());
    shirts.Add(shirtData);
}

listBox.ItemsSource = shirts;
```

Comment: tnx @Iron, I did that but had this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Viewer.DatabaseTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Could you show me the DatabaseTable class, it could be a IEnumerable.

Comment: I have improve the answer according to your appended questions below. It will work, but just as @KyloRen said, better way should be `ObservableCollection`, defining and binding only one time.

Comment: tnx @Iron, I added Database Table class to my question

Comment: I have made some modification according to the appended `GetTable` method, try again please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the property that is bound to `NamesTable` below.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NamesTable}}"
```

ie, assuming the property is a `list`, add and remove items as you would normally do with a list.

Comment: tnx @KyloRen, NamesTable is a DatabaseTable , shoud I convert it to list?

Comment: @samane, you should be binding to a list with `ItemsSource`. Make a list property ie,  `List<string> yourList = new List<string>();` and bind to that. Idealy you should use MVVM and bind to an `ObservableCollection`.